# using str.findall to retrieve the exact match from dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, string, dictionary

I have the following dictionary

```
dictionary = {"car":1234, "light-blue":112, "orange":34, "blue":1, "cargo yellow":35}
```

And the following dataframe

```
df_data = {"sentence": ["the summarine is a cargo yellow and orange", "the sky was an amazing light-blue, you should have seen it", "the grass is green", "why you face is purple?", "Light blue as you! HAHA", "Have you ever use the Jungle exploration?"], "extra":['a','b','c','d', 'e', 'f'] }  
df = pd.DataFrame(df_data)
```

Based on a previous question I have made, I was using this code:

```
df['new_col'] = df.sentence.str.extract(pat = f"({'|'.join(dictionary.keys())})")[0]
```

But I have two problems: the first is that in case I have multiple dictionary keys in the sentence, is not able to extract it; the second which is that it retrieves the word car even if is not present. To solve the first problem I used the following code:

```
df.sentence.str.findall(f"|".join(dictionary.keys())).apply(", ".join)
```

Which result in this:

```
0    car, orange
1     light-blue
2               
3               
4           blue
5
```

But still, I have the problem with car and in this case also with blue.   What instead, I would like to have is this:

```
0  cargo yellow, orange
1            light-blue
2                   nan  
3                   nan   
4                   nan
5                   nan
```

Furthermore do you have any suggestion in how I could change the code to have this result instead:

```
0  cargo yellow, orange
1            light-blue
2                   nan  
3                   nan   
4            light blue
5                   nan
```

EDIT: I have tried the following code:

```
for i in dictionary.keys():
    print(i,"\n",df.sentence.str.findall(rf'\b\W?{i}\W?\b'))
```

And in this case, the key 'car' is not retrieved but is not very efficient considering that my dictionary has 3000 key/value.

Thank you!

Comment: Add few rows of your sample data as well.

Comment: Sorry, the data were written without the space from ``` and so it was hidden. Added

Comment: `blue` is obviously going to match `Light blue`, Talking about the `car` I don't see that in the resulting string.

Comment: With the code I provided? I tried to run again the code after I cleaned the kernel, but still I have the car result.

Comment: It is somehow not here on my end, but that is also expected since `car` is contained in `cargo`

Comment: Any idea of how to not retrieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare input data:

```
data = {27695: 'I am legit happy because of these news.',
        143703: "Something seems suspicious.I can't recognize that...",
        ...
        48645: 'lol.',
        185265: 'Maybe there is a chance the infinity war sets are next'}

df = pd.DataFrame({"sentence": data.values()}, index=data.keys())
```

Find full words:

```
out = df.sentence.str.findall('|'.join([fr'\b{w}\b' for w in dictionary.keys()])) \
                     .apply(lambda l: ','.join(l))
```

Display only matched results:

```
>>> out[out != '']
56082      blue,orange
134801            blue
102078            blue
106617            blue
204968            blue
139796    cargo yellow
Name: sentence, dtype: object
```

Comment: In the small dataset I provide to you, it works. But when I tried to run on the original one I have this error ```sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found
```

Comment: Try to remove `.apply(lambda l: ','.join(l)`

Comment: Yep, I have done it and the result is something like this ```[(, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , )]``` I thinking of what the problem is. As input I have some string so it should work

Comment: I haven't solved the problem, and I don't know why. You are right I am going to give you accept your answer because on the small data your solution work

Comment: Ty. But it's possible for you to share your original dataframe?

Comment: I added a snippet of my data maybe you can help

Comment: I have solved. The problem was in the dictionary, some key had also the parenthesis and that was causing some trouble. I will give you accept your answer as correct.